# group rows with same id, pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here is the original data set

```
id         firstname    lastname      email               update date
A1         wendy         smith         ws@mail.com        2018-01-02
A1         wendy         smith         smith@mail.com     2019-02-03 
A2         harry         lynn          lynn@mail.com      2016-04-03
A2         harry                       harylynn@mail.com  2019-03-12
A3         tinna         dickey        tinna@mail.com      2016-04-03
A3         tinna         dickey        776-3384-333       2019-03-12
```

my design is to group rows with same id, if some columns with same id contain different values, keep the latest one.
So the result should be like this:

```
id         firstname    lastname      email               update date
A1         wendy         smith         smith@mail.com     2019-02-03 
A2         harry         lynn          harylynn@mail.com  2019-03-12
A3         tinna         dickey        tinna@mail.com      2019-03-12
```

currently, I try to use pandas groupby to group cell with the same value and keep different values in one cell separated by "," for later use(remove earlier data, make one cell one data ). BUt, I think what I am doing is not right...

```
df=df.groupby(['id']).agg({'first_name': lambda x:','.join(set(x))})
```

What if the latest value is a wrong value, do I need to store the conflict value to a new column for latter clean?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is the cell in `lastname` actually empty or `NaN`?

Comment: That could be user forgot to type in their Last name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `update_date` column is sorted ascending. And your empty cells are actual whitespaces, use `replace`, `ffill` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df_new = df.replace('', np.NaN).ffill().drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

If your empty cells are `NaN`, use:

```
df_new = df.ffill().drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

**Output**

```
   id firstname lastname              email update date
1  A1     wendy    smith     smith@mail.com  2019-02-03
3  A2     harry     lynn  harylynn@mail.com  2019-03-12
```

If your data is not sorted, first do:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'update date'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't know ffill(), That would help.  What if, for example the latest email value is a wrong value like people accidentally left phone number in this cell. Do I need to keep the duplicate email in another column for latter compare?

Comment: That makes the question completely different to be honest, since you have to work with `regex` now. I see your original question as answered. Feel free to post another question with your 2nd problem.

Comment: Is there a way i can use id as the unique value and combine the emails to store 
I'll need the data to be as follows:
id firstname email
A1 wendy ws@email.com,smith@email.com

Answer (score 1):

i think this will solve

```
output = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["id"], keep='last')
```

Comment: note: OP might need to use `sort_values` to make sure the "latest" values are indeed last

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  since some earlier data may contain values that latest one doesn't have, like 'harry' in the fourth line doesn't have last name, I need to get the value from the earlier one. So drop after sort the date may not solve these kind of issue.